# Split dataset for multi-output image classification with threshold

Tags: python, scikit-learn, split

I use StratifiedShuffleSplit from sklearn.model_selection to split dataset. But it is just for 1 label. So how to Stratified split for both label, and add a threshold for the number of samples in each class in each label?
Sorry for my bad english.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=val_size, random_state=42)
for train_index, val_index in split.split(tdf, tdf['layout']):
    train_df = tdf.loc[train_index]
    val_df = tdf.loc[val_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate more on (in each label in each class) please?

This API can be used to ensure that both the **train and test sets** have the proportion of examples in each class. In other words, we use it to make sure that we will have samples from each class in both train and test sets. It does not handle the problem of imbalanced classes which is another problem.

If you mean 1 class by 1 label, then you need to check the number of classes before splitting

```
tdf['layout'].nunique()
```

The output should be: 2

Also, in your code you are only splitting the independent features (input) and not splitting the output/target (in your case: tdf['layout])

Add this line of code:

```
y_train, y_val = tdf['layout][train_index], tdf['layout][val_index]
```

Also, just make sure that *'layout'* column is dropped from tdf